# Yii2: filtering gridview from a form outside the header

Tags: yii2

Filters in the header are not friendly with mobile views. What is the best approach to remove filters in gridview's header and put them in a separated form or in a sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a separated form and render it in the same view  (eg: index ) you have gthe gridview  .. in thi case the search model should be render by the separated form and not by the gridview  ..

```
 <?php echo  $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]) ?>

 <?php 
     echo GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
             ......
        ]);

 ?>
```

you can find a useful guide in this yii2 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#separate-filter-form

Answer (score 1):

For scenarios where you want some filter outside the grid and rest as normal in the grid, I usually append hidden input inside the filter  and create input anywhere on a page which when changed, gets the value and appends to hidden input.

```
  <select id='attribute-filter'>
     <option value='1' <?=$searchModel->attribute == 1?'selected':''?> >Yes</option>
     <option value='2' <?=$searchModel->attribute == 2?'selected':''?> >No</option>
  </select>

  <?php
  echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'id' => 'grid-info',
            'columns' => [
                  'id',
                  'name'
             ],
        ]);?>
```

And use ajax to append and trigger change:

```
 //append hidden filter
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //usually filter table row uses 'tableid'-filter naming convention 
        $('#grid-info-filters').find('td:first-child').append('<input 
         type="hidden" name="searchModel[attribute]">');
    });

 //Apply Filter
  $('#attribute-filter').on('change', function(){
    $('input[name="searchModel[attribute]"]').val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
   });
```

I Understand this is a crude way of doing it but it works.If you have multiple filters you need outside, I would go with the _search.php way as pointed out by @ScaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

In the View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); ?>
...fields...
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
//...options...
]);?>
```

In the Controller:

```
$model = new Matchs();
$q = ...some empty/initial query...

if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->get()) ) {
   $q = //...Your query with form filters...
}

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'key'=> 'id',
            'allModels' => $q,
            'sort' => ['attributes' => ['id',
            'matchdate', 'schedule','teams', 'goals','comments']],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 15,
            ],
        ]);

return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'model' => $model]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Gridview Filters & Pjax Solution

For those needing to leverage a filter in addition to the Gridview filters wrapped in Pjax:

[image]

**File Stucture**

```
app/views/
 - index.php
 - blood_type_filter.js
app/models/
 - PeopleSearch.php
```

**view/index.php**

> Note: no `blood_type` in Gridview

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\DonorSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Donors';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
$this->registerJs($this->render('_blood_type_filter.js'));
?>
<div class="donor-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= Html::a('Create Donor', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <span class="pull-right">
                <label>Blood Type: </label>
                <select class="pull-right" id='select-blood-type' name='blood_type' onChange="applyBloodTypeFilter()">
                    <option value="O pos" selected>Type O+</option>
                    <option value="O neg">Type O-</option>
                    <option value="A pos">Type A-</option>
                    <option value="">Show All</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <?php Pjax::begin([
        'id' => 'pjax-donar-grid',
        'enablePushState'    => false, 
        'enableReplaceState' => false,
        'clientOptions'      => ['cache' => false],
    ]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            // 'id',
            'full_name',
            'occupation',
            'favorite_food',
            [
                'label' => 'Blood Type',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'filter' => null, 
                'value' => 'blood_type',
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**views/filter_script**

> Where the magic happens. I determined methods below based on reading the yii.Gridview.js applyFilter method.

A form is rebuilt and appended to the gridview when the filters are changed if using pjax. There is a gridview.beforeFilter event that occurs after the form is rebuilt at which type I append a field in the format of the other fields being submitted, i.e. `ModelSearch[column]`.

```
applyBloodTypeFilter = function() {
    $(".grid-view").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
}

$(document).on('beforeFilter', function(e) {
    var $el = $('#select-blood-type option:selected');
    if ($el) {
        var val = $el.val();
        console.log(val);
        console.log('Applying blood_type filter: ', val);
        
        var $form = $(".grid-view").find('form.gridview-filter-form');
        // yii.gridview.js will append input again from previous request that is updated in gridview->setting->filter_url, so lets remove.
        $form.find('input[name="DonorSearch[blood_type]"]').remove();
        $form.append(
            $('<input>').attr({
                type:  'hidden',
                name:  'DonorSearch[blood_type]'
            }).val(val)
        );

        console.table($form.serializeArray());
    }
});

$(function() {
    applyBloodTypeFilter();
});
```

**models/InventorySearch**

> Ensure you have the column marked as safe in your rules and a andFilter method.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['other_columns ... ', 'blood_type'],, 'safe']
    ];
}

// .... stuff between
// Ensure you have a filter in your search model

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'blood_type', $this->blood_type])
```

Comment: applyBloodTypeFilter(); is called right at the beginning, doesn't the page end up in a loop since every time page is loaded, the filter is applied?

Comment: It shouldnt since that is outside the pjax container.